# Read large data of excel using c#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a large excel file (.xlsb) with around 300 000 rows and 30 columns. I can read this data using Oledb but its taking approx.. 100 sec to read the whole file.How can I read this much of large data within a minute.

Comment: Use Excel interop for this.

Comment: Maybe you can try: https://npoi.codeplex.com/

Comment: Once you read it, what are you doing with it?

Comment: Interop would still be slow. If they were xlsx files I would recommend EPPlus. It reads the underlying xml, but xlsb is binary. Can you save them as xlsx or are you stuck with xlsb? It might be worth a quick test to save one as xlsx and read it with EPPlus and see how fast/slow it is.

Comment: yes nickfinity I need my file to ne .xlsb format only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend a third-party control called FlexCel for speed in processing Excel documents. http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp

Alternately, if you can rather get the data in a CSV format (comma separated value) it's quite easy to write a fast robust CSV parser using the standard .NET classes.